# Using .includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So here is the question for the problem.

*Write a function named checkForPlagiarism that takes two arguments:
an array of all of the responses for a given person
a string of text that represents an external source
For each essay question in the listed responses, check whether or not the response value contains the given string. If it does, return true; otherwise, return false.*

The function is supposed to check the response in the argument with the responses in the responses array. Can't seem to get it to return the correct boolean

So here is the repl.it. Prompt 3 is the one I am completely stuck on.

https://repl.it/@AngeloLongoria/Take-Home-Science-Quiz

Comment: Please update your code to show how you are calling `checkForPlagiarism` and what params are you passing to it?

Comment: check with what? i dont see any other array

Comment: It correctly return `false` because none of the responses have *"lysosomes are cellular organelles"* value. If you try with *"Esophagus"*, it returns true

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what exactily is the definition of plagiarism here? E.g. the 'Prostaglandins'-question: if I give the (wrong) input `"True"`, would that be plagiarism?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider using `array.filter` instead of looping.

```
function checkForPlagiarism(responses, input) {
    return responses.filter(x => x.response === input);
}

result = checkForPlagiarism(response, "Esophagus") // 1

if (result.length) {
    console.log("That answer has already been given")
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

As gorak suggests, `filter` in the above example could be replaced by `some`, which would return a boolean rather than a number of matches, and would also stop searching the array once a match was found, which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this(using `some`):

```
text="lysosome";
getResult = responses.some((elem)=>elem.response.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase()));
```

Since you just have to return the boolean value if it is present in the array or not, `some` will do this for you.

I hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your `container` array.

After looping the value of `container` is an array of string.

```
[
    "Metaphase",
    "Esophagus",
    "A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in …s that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.",
    "True"
]
```

`include` is looking for an exact match. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes.

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing the strange definition of plagiarism, [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would do what is asked I suppose. Snippet for exact match and "*the response value contains the given string*" (fuzzy).

```js
const responses = getResponses();
// strict equality check
const checkForPlagiarism = (responses, answer) =>
  responses.find(v => v.response === answer) ? true : false;
// check substring in some response
const checkForPlagiarismFuzzy = (responses, answer) => 
  responses.find(v => new RegExp(answer, "gi").test(v.response)) ? true : false;

console.log('[exact] "lysosomes are cellular organelles" =>',
  checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'lysosomes are cellular organelles'));
console.log('[exact] "Esophagus" =>', checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'Esophagus'));
console.log('[exact "True" =>', checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'True'));
console.log('[fuzzy] "a membrane-bound organelle" =>',
  checkForPlagiarismFuzzy(responses, 'a membrane-bound organelle'));
console.log('[fuzzy] "a membrane-bound stomach" =>', checkForPlagiarismFuzzy(responses, 'a membrane-bound stomach'));
console.log('[fuzzy] "Tru" =>', checkForPlagiarismFuzzy(responses, 'Tru'));

function getResponses() {
  return [{
      question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
      response: 'Metaphase',
      isCorrect: true,
      isEssayQuestion: false
    },
    {
      question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
      response: 'Esophagus',
      isCorrect: true,
      isEssayQuestion: false
    },
    {
      question: 'What are lysosomes?',
      response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
      isCorrect: true,
      isEssayQuestion: true
    },
    {
      question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
      response: 'True',
      isCorrect: false,
      isEssayQuestion: false
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by adding multiple condition something like this

```
if ( response.includes(userinput) && isEssayQuestion ){
    return true;
}
```

if above condition does not match

```
return false;
```

Hope this helps